# Google Maps V3 - In tab, trigger resize on tab click, getBounds is confused about map bounds

Tags: user-interface, tabs, maps

I've have found some weirdness with Maps V3 in jQuery UI tabs. 
A common issue, when a map is initialized in a hidden tab, it gets confused and doesn't know how big to make the map. 
The solution for this is:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({show: function(e, ui) {if (ui.index == 5) {google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");   }     }});
```

That works fine. That maps resizes visually in the tab.

The next issue, perhaps less commonly, is that I want to load markers based on the latLng of my site's users. When I try to load them via the init function, the getBounds appear to be the same... I assume it's the same issue. The map is confused about the load size.

Like the trigger for resize, is there a way to trigger a function and pass the map DOM info after it has been initialized? I am so new to this!